# Modify style of Android items in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-actionbar, android-menu

How can I modify the style of the items on the Action bar of an Android Application?

I tryed the following:

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Light</item>

<style name="ActionBar.Light" parent="@style/ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#FF00FF</item>
</style>
```

The background of the Action bar I was able to modify, but not the text Colors of the items in the Action bar. How can I do it?

EDIT:

I tried pretty much all the `android:action` attributes I found, but I couldn't manage to change anything other than the background. Only the first `<item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>` of the following code makes changes on my code. No matter which values I put on the Test style, it doesn't change anything. Why is it happening?

```
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Light</item>

<style name="ActionBar.Light" parent="@style/ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@style/Test</item>
        <item name="android:actionButtonStyle">@style/Test</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@style/Test</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextAppearance">@style/Test</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Test">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you want to change the color of the menu items in the action bar you have to set the actionMenuTextColor in your theme style.

```
<style name="PortfolioTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
   <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">#24598a</item>
   <item name="actionMenuTextColor">#24598a</item>
</style>
```

You don't define the menu item colors in the actionMenuTextAppearance!

Comment: Hello, I tried this solution. It changes the menu items color in action bar. But may sub menu items are not changing. What should i do to change the color or sub menu items.

Comment: Hi, you are probably talking about changing the overflow menu style. I am not really 100% sure about the solution but try checkign these links:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/actionbarsherlock/5lHOKNlXn_4

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14859794/actionbar-styled-overflow-menu-items

Comment: This is the sh*t that did it for me. It also works on the ActionBarCompat (the v7 support package for Android). Having a quick look in the resource files provided for the ActionBarCompat by the support package also confirms the `actionMenuTextColor` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color by:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
<item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
<item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
<item name="android:textColor">@color/red</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

Comment: Didn't work here. This android:titleTextStyle makes no effect in my code at all, I had already tried it before though.

Comment: I guess this is only for the Title of the application, not the title of the itens.

Comment: Thank you for the link, really helpfull. I just updated my question.