# Actionbar styled overflow menu items

Tags: android, themes, android-actionbar

I need to make fully custom overflow menu items (different background colors as minimum as showed on picture).

[image: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/7771649/overflow.png]

Is it possible?

Comment: It's [possible to change the color of *all* overflow menu items](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/actionbarsherlock/5lHOKNlXn_4), but I don't believe it's possible to set them individually.

Comment: But I need different styles for each item. I know one way to do it - PopupWindow with own layout. But it's not so elegant like popup menu in action bar.

Comment: You can achieve this setting the adapter of you action list.In adapter you can set different background colors.

Comment: @MohammadImran Please give me a little more details!

Comment: i have answered your question.If you need more help,i'll provide you.

Comment: @user2069363 respond to my answer,if you got you answer.

Answer (score 5):

Last day i have to implement Action Bar Sherlock.And my case was same as yours. I have implement Adapter for my navigation List.Let say:

```
public class MyNavigationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context mContext = null;
    String[] mTitles;
    LayoutInflater mLayOutInflater = null;

    public MyNavigationAdapter(Context context, String[] titles) {
        this.mContext = context;
        this.mTitles = titles;
        mLayOutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mTitles.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int arg0) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int arg0) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (view == null)
            view = mLayOutInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_list_custom_row, parent,false);
        TextView rowName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        rowName.setText(mTitles[position]);
        rowName.setBackground(your desire drawle);// yo

u can also set color etc.
//OR

if(position%2==0)
        rowName.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        else
            rowName.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
        return view;
    }

}
```

After this,you have to write these line of code in your Activity onCreate methos.

```
  ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);
actionBar.setListNavigationCallbacks(mNavigationAdapterObj, mNavigationListner);
```

for more information .Consult [here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Dropdown)

Comment: Good solution! But I prefer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14123377/2069363 Because it allows me to create spinner with overflow menu icon on the same place like original overflow menu.

Comment: yes,you can also add icon ,if you want. I can update my answer for icons if you want.

Comment: that is same solution,basic theme is same. Accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom view for each MenuItem.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    menu.add("test").setActionView(R.layout.custom_action_menu_item);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#setActionView%28int%29

Comment: It works when MenuItem showed in action bar. But doesn't work when menu item inside overflow menu.

Answer (score 0):

This one https://stackoverflow.com/a/14123377/2069363 works for me!

> You can create such behavior using Spinner (or IcsSpinner for ActionBarSherlock) in action layout of a menu item. Though you have to use a little trick - hide the currently selected item.