# MenuItem custom view, with showAsAction=never

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock

I'm trying to use my own layout (`R.layout.update_button`) as an action bar menu item view.

The item declation is as follows:

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_update"
    android:checkable="true"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="Title"/>
```

With the following code on the `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` :

```
View updateView = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
            .inflate(R.layout.update_button, null);
update.setActionView(updateView);
```

The problem is that tihis only works when `android:showAsAction` is set to `always`. However when it is set to `never`, I only see the menu title ("Title") without any custom layout of mine.

Is there a way to show the custom layout even when `showAsAction="never"` ?

Comment: It sounds like you want to change the Overflow Menu's layout, check out: [Actionbar styled overflow menu items](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14859794/1267661)

Comment: I don't want to implement a list. It's just a single menu item to which I want to add a subtitle. I figured I could do that by making my own layout, but it doesn't work when it's in an overflow menu (only works whilst on the action bar)