# Changing action overflow text color in the ActionBar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

I have been struggling to change the text color of the Action Overflow item in the action bar. I use v7 AppCompat and Light theme with Dark actionbar.

[image]

`actionMenuTextColor` doesn't seems to do anything. I need to change it to a black text? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You might already have your answer but maybe somebody has the same question so heres my solution to that:

just use "Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" or something with dark action bar

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a similiar post here:

[Modify style of Android items in the ActionBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323544/modify-style-of-android-items-in-the-actionbar)

Seems to be related to setting the particular style of the actionbar instead of just the `actionmenutextcolor` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the Theme's itemTextAppearance as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19212678) worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Fairly late for an answer but maybe it helps somebody else.

Use `android:actionBarWidgetTheme` (`actionBarWidgetTheme` if you use any of the ActionBarCompat themes as your base theme) to set the text color to black `<item name="android:textColor">#000</item>`

See [a blog post here](http://daniel-codes.blogspot.com.au/2012/11/the-unknown-style-actionbarwidgettheme.html) that explains how to set the `android:radioButtonStyle`  in the same fashion.

Answer (score -1):

```
<item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/PopupMenu.recipe</item>
<style name="PopupMenu.recipe" 
    parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.Base.ActionButton.Overflow">  
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item> 
</style>
```